# get the value of a matrix

Tags: javascript, matrix, sum

i am new to javascript and a have a problem. i am using OPL for my mathematical programming and in my execute block i can use javascript.

I have a 3D matrix :

```
A[tier][row][column]=
[[[ 1 7 13 19 25 ] 
[ 3 9 15 21 27 ]
[ 5 11 17 23 29 ]
[ 7 13 19 25 31 ]],

[[2 8 14 20 26] 
[4 10 16 22 28]
[6 12 18 24 30]
[8 14 20 26 32]], ];
```

and a second boolean matrix like this :

```
B[t][r][c] = 
[[[ 1 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 1 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 0 ]]

[0 0 1 0 0] 
[0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]], ];
```

Now i want to sum up the values of my A matrix, where matrix B is one. Here it would be like : 1+11+14+10 ( just to make clear what my question is).

My idea is :

```
for (var t in Tier)
for (var r in Row)
for (var c in Column) {
val = 0;

if ( B[t][r][c] == 1 ) 
//get the value of A[t][r][c] and add it to val and give the sum of val out
}
```

Could you help me please? I dont know how to formulate it..

kind regards

t.

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate the array `a` with [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and test if `b` contains a truthy value for summing.

```js
var a = [[[1, 7, 13, 19, 25], [3, 9, 15, 21, 27], [5, 11, 17, 23, 29], [7, 13, 19, 25, 31]], [[2, 8, 14, 20, 26], [4, 10, 16, 22, 28], [6, 12, 18, 24, 30], [8, 14, 20, 26, 32]]],
    b = [[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]],
    sum = 0;

a.forEach(function (t, i) {
    t.forEach(function (r, j) {
        r.forEach(function (c, k) {
            sum += b[i][j][k] ? c : 0;
        });
    });
});

console.log(sum);
```

ES6 with [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

```js
var a = [[[1, 7, 13, 19, 25], [3, 9, 15, 21, 27], [5, 11, 17, 23, 29], [7, 13, 19, 25, 31]], [[2, 8, 14, 20, 26], [4, 10, 16, 22, 28], [6, 12, 18, 24, 30], [8, 14, 20, 26, 32]]],
    b = [[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]],
    sum = a.reduce((s, t, i) => 
              s + t.reduce((s, r, j) => 
                  s + r.reduce((s, c, k) => s + b[i][j][k] * c, 0), 0), 0);

console.log(sum);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it with simple for-loop:

```
var A = [[[ 1 7 13 19 25 ] 
[ 3 9 15 21 27 ]
[ 5 11 17 23 29 ]
[ 7 13 19 25 31 ]],

[[2 8 14 20 26] 
[4 10 16 22 28]
[6 12 18 24 30]
[8 14 20 26 32]], ],
    B = [[[ 1 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 1 0 0 0 ]
[ 0 0 0 0 0 ]]

[0 0 1 0 0] 
[0 1 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]
[0 0 0 0 0]], ],
    maxTier=A.length,
    maxRow = A[0].length,
    maxColumn = A[0][0].length,
    val = 0;

for(var t=0;t<maxTier;t++){
for(var r=0;r<maxRow;r++){
for(var c=0;c<maxColumn;c++){
if ( B[t][r][c] == 1 ) 
 val+=A[t][r][c];
}

}

}
}
```